# fatal read error in cloning/pulling git repository

Tags: git

I'm using Git for Windows (git version 1.7.4.msysgit.0) on my system, and it's worked perfectly most of the time, but today at uni I'm having problems whenever I try to `git clone` or `git pull` or `get fetch` a repository (for reference it's git://git.ffmpeg.org/rtmpdump ) and I get:

```
fatal: read error: Invalid argument
```

Using GIT_TRACE=1 shows the problem with git fetch, but it fails no matter the arguments. Could it be to do with my network or my local copy of git?

Comment: I think it's the network I'm on at Uni. Pulling the same repo from home worked fine with no changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `git fetch` doesn't work at all for you with `https://` or `git://`, it really sounds like a corrupt installation, or a bug. If you'd like, head over to the [msysGit mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/msysgit/) to log your bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have **other version** of `mingw32.dll` in your computer. You need the correct `mingw32.dll` on the PATH **before** other versions.