# fetch/pull error - fatal: read error: Invalid argument

Tags: git

as per this article http://www.geekaholic.org/2012/05/peer-to-peer-collaborative-development.html i tried the following for peer-peer sharing.

On Client 1

> 1. Clone from central repo
> 2. Make some changes and commit
> 3. from the parent directory of this clone - git daemon --export-all --base-path=.

On Client 2

> 1. Clone from same central repo
> 2. git remote add new git://machine-name/repo-name
> 3. git fetch new 
>      fetch/pull error - fatal: read error: Invalid argument

When i create another clone in the same Client1, and do the same steps - the fetch or pull works.
From Client 2, using IP address instead of the system name - same result
From Client 2, when i cloned from Client 1 (git clone git://machine-name/repo-name) the clone was succesful.

What could be causing the fetch error?

Comment: Maybe the name "new" causes the error because it conflicts with some keyword..?

Comment: no, i just used it as an example here

Comment: looks like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224822/fatal-read-error-in-cloning-pulling-git-repository . Try another way to access the remote machine, like http. Also try on Client1, in another folder `git remote add new path/to/repo`